# What is a difference between <-> and <@> operators when comparing Points?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

```
SELECT 
  point(45,45) <-> point(46,46) AS val1
 ,point(45,45) <@> point(46,46) AS val2
```

and result:

```
val1: 1.4142135623731
val2: 84.3733913253679
```

I know that `<@>` returns distance in miles but what returns `<->` operator? I know that `<->` can return similarity between strings but how it returns similarity between points?

Comment: `1.4142135623731` is `SQRT(2)`.  It's probably just taking the distance in units on a flat surface (i.e. not the curved Earth).

Comment: It's returning the euclidean distance between the points. In this case: `sqrt((46-45)^2 + (46-45)^2))`